# How do I set Meteor to not cache anything for a specific page?

Tags: caching, meteor, webbrowser-control, cache-control

I am working on a project where I am using Meteor as an implementation.  There are set of pages that are being cached and there's no concern.

However, there is one page in the project that I am trying to set for no-cache.  How do I achieve that?

EDITED:

Based on chosen accepted answer; I achieved the desired result with this wrapping code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(function (req, res, next) {
            res.setHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache');
            res.setHeader('expires', '0');
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.setHeader('charset', 'utf-8');
            next();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You are also changing the `Content-Type` of *all* resources served by Meteor, including anything in your `public` folder. E.g., images will also be served as `Content-Type: text/html` which haphazardly works in Chrome, but not in other browsers (such as IE). Also scripts are declared as `text/html`, which may also cause trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WebApp](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/webapp) to configure cache headers:

```
//Server code
WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use('/noCachePagePath', function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache');
  next();
});
```

Comment: I achieved the desired result is to include this code inside the wrapper of `if (Meteor.isServer) { }` since API doc stated that this kind of code needs to be from server-side.