# How much of mini mongodb is kept after restarting meteor app

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I'm wondering how much data is kept in mini mongodb (client side) after a meteor app restarts.  It seems like the user collection keeps the connected user information, since my app sign in automatically in offline mode, but I could not find any other collections I had locally before the restart (using the app offline).

I'm trying to allow my users to access some data when they have previously restarted their phone or app, perhaps they dont have internet connection at the moment.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To see how minimongo handles your data in chrome, checkout [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meteor-minimongo-explorer/bpbalpgdnkieljogofnfjmgcnjcaiheg?hl=en) or [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meteor-devtools/ippapidnnboiophakmmhkdlchoccbgje?hl=en). You will see that every time you refresh a logged-in user, Meteor only subscribes to what Meteor.user() returns.

I have not tried this. But here's how how someone [solved this exact issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18734727/3161066) with [GroundDB](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db) and configuring [appcache](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/appcache.html).